# Is $\inf_{[0,\:t]}f=\inf_{[0,\:t]\:\cap\:\mathbb Q}f$ even when $f$ is only left-continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

Let $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$. If $f$ is continuous, then $$\inf_{[0,\:t]}f=\inf_{[0,\:t]\:\cap\:\mathbb Q}f\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\tag1$$ by the intermediate value theorem. Can $(1)$ be shown in the case of left-continuity of $f$ too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Suppose $L=\inf_{[0,t]} f$. If $f(0) = L$, we're done, since $0$ is rational.

Otherwise, for any $\epsilon>0$, there is some $c$ such that $c \in (0,t]$ and $|f(c)-L| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. In addition, by left-continuity, you can find some rational $d \in [0,c)$ such that $|f(d) - f(c)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Hence

$$\epsilon = \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2}>|f(c)-L| + |f(d) - f(c)| \geq |f(d)-L|$$

In other words, there's rationals in $[0,t]$ which $f$ maps arbitrarily close to $L$.

Comment: We can also use contradiction: If $L<M=\inf _{[0,t]\cap \mathbb Q}f$  then there exists $x\in (0,t)$ \ $\mathbb Q$ with$ f(x)<(L+M)/2.$ But  there exists a  sequence $(q_n)_n$ of rationals in $(0,x)$ converging to $x, $ implying $ f(x)= \lim_{n\to \infty} f(q_n)\geq M>(L+M)/2>f(x),$  a paradox.............+1

Comment: Did you implicitly assume $L>-\infty$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Yes, I did. However, you can easily modify the argument to take care of that. 

If $$\inf f(x)_{x \in [0, t]}= -\infty$$ then $$\inf f(x)_{x \in (0, t)}= -\infty$$ so given any $M>0$, there is a $c \in (0,t)$ such that $f(c) < -M$. By left continuity, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $q \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (c - \delta, c)$, we also have $f(q) < -M$. 

Since $M$ is arbitrary, we conclude $$\inf f(x)_{x \in [0, t] \cap \mathbb{Q}}= -\infty$$